# Filter an enum based on case names in swift

Tags: arrays, enums, swift5

I have this code:

```
enum CountryInfoColor : String, CaseIterable {
    case Canada    = "green1"
    case USA       = "green2"
    case Brazil    = "green3"
    case Australia = "purple1"
    case Germany   = "purple2"
    case China     = "purple3"
    case Japan     = "blue1"
    case Mexico    = "blue2"
}
```

The enum that I have is over 1000 lines long, and I am looking for a way to filter the enum based on the case names as each case name is a unique element.
Something like this did not work of course:
`var enumArrayFiltered = CountryInfoColor.allCases.filter{ $0.contains("Canada") }`  Because $0 has no member 'contains' .

I know it's easily possible to use filter and contain functions on an array of enums based on their rawValues like this:`var enumFilteredRawValues = CountryInfoColor.allCases.filter{$0.rawValue.contains("greeen") }`
But is it really not possible to easily use filter and contain functions based on the enum cases themselves?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Mirror](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mirror) for this.

The easiest way to do that is to let this `String` initializer handle it for you:

```swift
// [USA, Australia]
CountryInfoColor.allCases.filter { String(describing: $0).contains("A") }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand how to filter based on the enum's rawValue, that's not a problem, I'm looking for a way to filter based on the name of the cases itself, not the rawValue. For example, all the cases with the name "United" in the case name, and then I will go ahead and use the rawValue data. Sorry if I didn't make that clear

Comment: Please improve the question. I can see this question in what you've written, now, but we had to do too much digging to get there. You just need a better example of how you actually want to filter.